# Op-amp, Finding the V0

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have to calculate Vo in this circuit. Unfortunately I am very confuse how to do that.
I know the current pass I(2ohm)= 0 and ix=0.

I choose 5Vx as a super node and because ix=0 then the whole current flows through 1ohm then v(x)=5v. but still I cant get the right answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feChl5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

This is my solution of the problem:

$$V_X = 5 (1) = 5 V $$

...

[image]

Comment: I have never seen the diamond symbols. Are they part of the ANSI standard that no one uses? Something used in simulation?

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer it is a controllable current/voltage source.

Comment: Where is Vo on the circuit and if this is an op-amp question why is the 3 ohm resistor and op-amp output not connected to anything?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to put 5 amperes into the inverting input of that comparator or op-amp. Maybe that's what blew the connection off the output.

Comment: Can you show some more steps of the process you have tried? Have you gotten *any* result?

Comment: Personally I would start by using the superposition principle on the independent sources to simplify the problem.

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer  There was a [thread about the controlled source (diamond) symbol](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/99232/7036).

Comment: The image is impossible to read, but there is good news! The site has a MathJax engine to write formulas in TeX syntax, can't you copy some of the steps here? I'll give you an example. Also, looking at the schematic I don't see any component designators (e.g. R1, R2...). Those are very important, especially if you seek for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach the problem.  First, *redraw the circuit for clarity*, e.g.,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBkcOi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*If* there's negative feedback present, the op-amp input terminals have the same voltage (virtual short circuit) and, since there is no current into either input terminal, it follows that

$$I_x = 0$$

Thus,

$$V_x = 5A \cdot R_3 = 5A \cdot 1 \Omega = 5V$$

which means

$$V_+ = V_- = 5V$$

Now, using [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem), write the equation for \$V_o\$ at the inverting input node:

$$5V = V_o \frac{R_4||R_5}{R_6 + R_4||R_5} + (2V + 5\cdot 5V)\frac{R_4||R_6}{R_5 + R_4||R_6}$$

Solving for \$V_0\$ yields

$$V_o = -23V$$